# Issues in developing on OSK5912 (OMAP Processor)

Tags: dsp, linux

I want to develop applications using [OSK5912](http://omap.spectrumdigital.com/osk5912/) - an OMAP DSP Kit. The problem is that the TI no longer provides development tools for the same as it is quite an old kit.

For developing apps on Linux, it uses Montavista Linux Pro ver 3.1, and I am not able to install it as Montavista has removed support for ver 3.1. Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know very little about Linux (not used it for years) but since there are no other answers (yet) I will post my thoughts:

Are you sure the PRO 5.0 version of Montavista will not support your board? I had a look on their website and on the board support page, if you select platform as PRO the OSK5912 is listed there (it says 3.1 but the filter is for 5.0, so maybe it covers previous releases), suggesting it may be supported. Here is the link:

[Board support page with PRO filter selected](http://www.mvista.com/boards.php?vendorsearch=&boardname=&archgroup=All&processor=&edition=PRO&v=All&a0=1)

I didn't check TI as I'm not sure exactly what you would be looking for, but often vendors will keep archives of old tools, so it's worth having a good look on their site for anything you need (or maybe send them a quick mail telling them what you are trying to do). Google is good at finding old software too, which may not be necessarily on the original vendors site (maybe an archive or torrent set up by someone else)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me make matters more clear. The OSK5912 includes the a DSP chip made by TI but the kit is made by Spectrum Digital (http://www.spectrumdigital.com/). The DSP chip requires Montavista Linux Pro version 3.1. The kit came with a CD which contains the software but it requires a registration to be done after which I can get a registration key to install the Montavista OS. Unfortunately, the Montavista does not support version 3.1 anymore, and thus I cannot get the registration key and hence I am unable to install the software. I hope its more clear now.

Comment: Ah, I see - I have had a good look through the various sites/manuals but unfortunately I couldn't come up with anything much as it seems both the 3.1 version and the TI chip are no longer supported, and as you say registration/password is needed. Hopefully someone with experience in this area will come forward. I would send emails to Montavista and ask on the TI forum in the meantime though. Good luck anyway, I hope you manage to find a solution.

Comment: Yes, will try mailing TI and Montavista but I dont think I will be lucky. I borrowed it from a lab where it has not been used since ages and hence noone there knows the password too :(. Anyways, thanks for your help and efforts! :)